# Send a html view as a pdf and email in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an MVC application that captures the details of students and displays them in a view that shows the data in table. Now I'm trying to convert the view into a PDF and email it to an email address

I've tried simple email code but that only allows for adding of an attachment, whereas i don't want to add as an attachment. I want to email the view

Comment: You can send in the `MailMessage body`, use `StringBuilder` to build up your string. Then set `IsBodyHtml` to true to support html tags.

Answer (score -1):

To Email the view you need to get the Html of that portion that you want to send inside Email like this:
HTML code:

```
<div id="emailContent">
    <div id="content">
       <p>  My Data for the email </p>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="sendEmail" >Send Email</a>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#sendEmail').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '',
         data: { content: $('#emailContent').html()}
     });
  });

});
```